# Full calendar business hours

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use business hour option, but I can't able to reflect the changes.

I want to display multiple business hours. Here is the code:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    businessHours:
        [
            {
                start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                end: '12:00', // an end time (12pm in this example)
                dow: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
            },
            {
                start: '12:00', // a start time (12pm in this example)
                end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                dow: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
            }]
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

like so

```
businessHours:
    {
                            
            start: '11:00',
            end:   '12:00',
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
```

in order to use different hours for different shifts -> use background events

```
events:
[
    {
        id:    'available_hours',
        start: '2015-1-13T8:00:00',
        end:   '2015-1-13T19:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
    },
    {
        id:    'work',
        start: '2015-1-13T10:00:00',
        end:   '2015-1-13T16:00:00',
        constraint: 'available_hours'
    }
]
```

For more information, see this link,
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint/

There's several different ways you can approach this, depending on how you use the calendar. Hopefully the flexibility of the constraints will help you get what you need done.

Pretty glad this feature finally showed up!

Comment: Thanks bro, 

i tried its working fine, but its not working for multiple business hours on daily basis(i mean shift)

shift1 : 8 -> 12
shift2 : 14 -> 20

var businessHours = 
    [{"start": '08:00:00', "end": '12:00:00',"dow": [1, 2, 3, 4]
     },{
  "start": '14:00:00', "end": '20:00:00', "dow": [1, 2, 3, 4]
      }];
its not working

Comment: I recommend taking advantage of the background events for that. Check them out in the documentation. They work more like events, but you can then attach them to functionality of other events. I'll add that to my answer if that's ok.

Comment: The api is a bit different in v4. Use `startTime`, `endTime` and `daysOfWeek` instead of `dow`. [see breaking changes](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#business-hours)

Comment: @DHFW i have same requirment... can you put answer how you solved it?

Comment: @joy sure. This is for FullCalendar.io version 5.3.0: 
`
[
  {
    "startTime": "10:30",
    "endTime": "16:30",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  },
  {
    "startTime": "9:00",
    "endTime": "16:30",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  }
]
`

Comment: @DHFW i am using the same version

Comment: @DHFW here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000576/fullcalendar-io-add-multiple-business-hours-for-1-day

Answer (score 1):

I have to show FullCaledar Time Slot for 8AM to 8PM fixed, so I have did some R&D, and apply following options, and it seems working fine!!! Cheers.

```
jq('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today,month,agendaWeek,resourceDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        allDaySlot: false,
        axisFormat: 'h:mm A',
        timeFormat: 'h:mm T',
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '20:00:00',
```

Use,
**minTime: '08:00:00',
maxTime: '20:00:00'**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

on the other hand, you can define working hours and days.

```
businessHours: [{
                        daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7],
                        startTime: '08:00',
                        endTime: '23:00'
                    },
                    {
                        daysOfWeek: [4],
                        startTime: '08:00',
                        endTime: '16:00'
                    },
                    {
                        daysOfWeek: [5],
                        startTime: '15:00',
                        endTime: '23:00'
                    }
                ]
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In version 4 :

```
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Monday - Thursday

  startTime: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  endTime: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
}
```

You may also break your business hour declaration into parts, in an array of objects, for additional control:

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
    startTime: '08:00', // 8am
    endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
  },
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
    startTime: '10:00', // 10am
    endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
  }
]
```

In version 3 :

```
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Monday - Thursday

  start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
}
```

You may also break your business hour declaration into parts for additional control (added in v2.9.1):

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
  {
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
    start: '08:00', // 8am
    end: '18:00' // 6pm
  },
  {
    dow: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
    start: '10:00', // 10am
    end: '16:00' // 4pm
  }
]
```