# Variable business hours in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working with FullCalendar and I'm using it for a business which has varying hours

- Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri is 09:00 - 17:00.
- Thu is 09:00 - 19:00.

  ```
  businessHours: {
      start: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
      end: '17:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
      dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 5]
          // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
          // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
  }
  ```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What are you trying to create with Fullcalendar exactly?  what do you have so far?

Comment: Have you tried using an array of objects?

Comment: I'm just playing around at the minute seeing what I can do with it. I was wondering if I could do it out of the box. I'll have a play with the array of object or even making a new object. It's walking dead time at the minute. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Blazemonger That should be the way to do it, but it's not supported currently. The best way to achieve this would be to use background events. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27695472/728393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variable hours for business hours, you need to use background events like this:

```
events:
[
    {
        id:    'available_hours',
        start: '2015-1-13T8:00:00',
        end:   '2015-1-13T19:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
    },
    {
        id:    'available_hours',
        start: '2015-1-14T8:00:00',
        end:   '2015-1-14T17:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
    },
    {
        id:    'work',
        start: '2015-1-13T10:00:00',
        end:   '2015-1-13T16:00:00',
        constraint: 'available_hours'
    }
]
```

Notice in the last event it has the constraint filled in? This says that this can only be placed within an available hours slot. Using constraints, you can make flexible business hours.

For more information, see this link,
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Adding an event for each business hour, like so:

```
{
  ...
  events: [
    // business hours 1
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '09:00',
        end: '17:00',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4], // monday - thursday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    },
    // business hours 2
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '15:00',
        dow: [6], // saturday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    }],
 ...
}
```

**NOTE :** `className` and `rendering` are important options for this to work.

Good Luck.