# Add multiple business hours for 1 day and show business hours in Month View

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar.io.

```
    businessHours: [
    
    {
      daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3], 
      startTime: '10:00',
      endTime: '12:00', 
    },
    {
      daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3], 
      startTime: '15:00',
      endTime: '18:00', 
    }

   ]
```

I have one custom setting for a store on my website where they are only open between 10 Am to 12 PM and from 3 pm to 6 pm, I am using the full calendar to show their timing but here when I apply this setting its not working.

How can I show grey background during other timing which is not in business hours (i.e in between 12 PM to 3 PM)?

Comment: Your code works fine - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZELaVvd . It's unclear what you think the problem is? Are you seeing a different behaviour? If so, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. enough code and data that we could run it and the problem would occur. Thanks.

Comment: I want to show half background in month view as per time is it possible? @ADyson

Comment: No, because the month view has no concept of time. It can only show days. There is no grid within each day which represents individual times.